# Early Error in annex semantics of GlobalDeclarationInstantiation

Tags: ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

I couldn't find any sources speaking about the next point in specification (let it be [GlobalDeclarationInstantiation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-web-compat-globaldeclarationinstantiation)):

> ii. If replacing the **FunctionDeclaration** f with a
> **VariableStatement** that has F as a **BindingIdentifier** would not produce
> any Early Errors for script, then

I don't understand this step, what would it be demonstrating this error?

I am trying to figure out this step in annex. So if we don't do replacements FunctionDeclartion with the VariableStatement, we won't get the error. Conversily we will get the error, if we do this replacements. What is example of it then?

Comment: This might be a language problem, but… "*So if we don't do replacements, we won't get the error.*" - doesn't matter. The if conditions asks what would happen if we *did do* the replacement. "*Conversily we will get the error, if we do this replacements.*" - no, not in all cases a replacement would cause an error.

Comment: @Bergi I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only of the [*Script* early errors](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-scripts-static-semantics-early-errors) that I can see possibly applying to that replacement is

> It is a Syntax Error if any element of the LexicallyDeclaredNames of `ScriptBody` also occurs in the VarDeclaredNames of `ScriptBody`.

So let's assume the script

```js
let x = 42;
{
  function x() {}
  console.log('block', typeof x);
}
console.log('global', typeof x, typeof window.x);
```

Now if we did replace the function declaration with the respective variable declaration, we'd get the script

```js
let x = 42;
{
  var x;
  console.log('block', typeof x);
}
console.log('global', typeof x, typeof window.x);
```

which causes a syntax error. So it does *not* run the conditional steps to create a global variable for the function.

If there is no collision with the lexical variables declared by the same script, the legacy web compatibility semantics do take effect:

```js
let y = 42;
{
  function x() {}
  console.log('block', typeof x);
}
console.log('global', typeof x, typeof window.x);
```

Comment: A little additional question: when will that replacing be performed? Until evaluating script, or when this step will be performing

Comment: No replacing will be performed at all. It's a hypothetical question in subjunctive mood: if we *did* do the replacement, *would* it lead to an early error?

Comment: So checking of replacement can't be hypothetical, can it? Do we should do in realization this check? If we have replacement step, then I don't understand follow step: `1. If env.HasLexicalDeclaration(F) is false, then`. Replacement step overlap this step because when we will reach it: `env.HasLexicalDeclaration` It always returns `false`, since we don't have lexical declarations due replacement step. If I am mistaking, point me please where.

Comment: `env.HasLexicalDeclaration(F)` will be `true` if some other (previous) script did declare a lexical variable with that name. It wouldn't trigger an early error. Personally I think it could have been less confusing - e.g. swapping the steps to first create the lexical variables then only testing for existence of the bindings - but probably the spec authors either wanted to safeguard this against possible other early errors (that might be introduced in the future), or I'm missing some other early error cases that already exist.

Comment: I've checked included two js files and I get an error in second one where I only declared function in Block and no more anywhere else. I am confused

Comment: Hm, that sounds like a bug to me. I can reproduce it both in Chrome and FF though.

Comment: I wondered by this, that's why I am confused additional step `env.HasLexicalDeclaration(F)`